# Download data using googledrive R package

Tags: r

I am trying to run analysis on metabolomics data in R. I am following the pipeline given by MetaboAnalystR (https://www.metaboanalyst.ca/docs/RTutorial.xhtml).

I can not download the data. The pipeline uses googledrive, however, I can not get authorization to the data. I have tried to access it with 2 different accounts, and I also tried with connection to different internet connections. Do any of you have an idea of what to do?

This is the code from the website:

```
## Setting the data depositing folder
data_folder_Sample <- "~/Data_IBD"
data_folder_QC <- "~/QC_IBD"
```

```
type h# Use Google API for data downloading here. 
# Please "install.packages('googledrive')" and "install.packages('httpuv')"first.
library(googledrive);
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
# Please authorize your google account to access the data
dl <- drive_download(
  as_id("10DBpPEWy2cZyXvmlLOIfpwqQYwFplKYK"), path = temp, overwrite = TRUE)
# Setting your own date file folder
out <- unzip(temp, exdir = data_folder_QC)
# Date files for parameters optimization are deposited below
out
```

```
# Now, download the small example data for comparison between CD vs. nonIBD
temp <- tempfile(fileext = ".zip")
dl <- drive_download(
  as_id("1-wlFUkzEwWX1afRWLJlY_KEJs7BfsZim"), path = temp, overwrite = TRUE)
# Setting the date file folder
out <- unzip(temp, exdir = data_folder_Sample)
# Date files for normal processing example are deposited below
out
```

I get this error:
Authentication complete.
Error in `map()`:
ℹ In index: 1.
Caused by error in `.f()`:
! Client error: (403) Forbidden
Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
PERMISSION_DENIED
• message: Insufficient Permission
• domain: global
• reason: insufficientPermissions

All the best,
Charlotte